# Summary for every chapter

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning

I'd like to have a summary for every chapter like in this picture. how to do it? Thank you :) [image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE... Hope you are expecting `minitoc`, please refer the documentation of package usage...

Comment: Exactly this is what I am searching for, thank you @MadyYuvi.